# What should happen when I comment on a Newsfeed post status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, facebook, database-design

A newsfeed has a list of some activities that happens in an app.

A newsfeed from facebook, for example, combines

- **Group name changes [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqAz7.png)]**
- **Status about people going to an event [[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86c9T.png)]**
- **Update status** [[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mg3Jz.png)]
- etc..

---

Fig **1**

[image: Fig 1]

Fig **2**

[image]

Fig **3**

[image]

---

These mixed activities are combined into a feed and them displayed.
Notice that each of them can be Liked, Commented, etc...

But in the newsfeed, its not the real object there. For example, for the [[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mg3Jz.png)] "hello world", this activity is referencing a original Post, but in the newsfeed is another record that summarizes the post and is the one that is seen (activity).

Suppose that the Post has the ID #111 and the entry of the activity that represents it is #222.

When I comment the post [[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mg3Jz.png)], what params will I have send to my server? Need I reference the id from the activity or the post?

I think that I should send the ID from the post #111, and in the server side I create the comment record and them generate another activity for this referencing the parent activity "hello world" [[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mg3Jz.png)].

But remembering that the newsfeed has a lot of types os objects and its not seems right to send only the ID in this case, because I will have to know what I am commenting or liking (Post, Question, etc..). So there's something wrong.

The idea is that I need to extend the basic public activity ([https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity/), http://public-activity-example.herokuapp.com/feed) to allow comments and likes.

I need some advices please.

Comment: Your question isn't clear - what are you doing exactly?

Comment: The question is how to make a comment in an activity item

Comment: Where are you retrieving the items? if it's via the `feed` connection, add the comment to the `comments` connection of the feed story; if you don't know the story ID yet because you've just posted the activity, add it to the activity instance ID you received as the response when you posted the activity

Comment: hmm. I receive a list of stories. these stories have its own id. what i'm asking: is the story id of the "hello world" #222 that I have to send to the server? thanks for the attention.

Comment: in general, you post to the `/comments` connection of whatever story you want to comment on; if the story is a story ABOUT another object you can also comment on the object directly, but you'd need to extract the object ID from the attachment - in most cases you'll just be replying to the ID of the item you retrieved from the `feed` connection already